Excel Macro Compile Error - Argument not Optional
I am getting an error message when I run my vba code in excel. The error message is a compile error with a message "Argument not Optional". I do not know where I am going wrong in the code.

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True

If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Range("K15:K31"))) Is Nothing Then
If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 43 Then
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
ActiveCell.Value = ""
Else: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 43
ActiveCell.Value = ChrW(&H2713)
ActiveCell.Font.ColorIndex = 2
End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Set Cancel = True

If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Range("K15:K31"))) Is Nothing Then
If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 48
ActiveCell.Value = "N/A"
ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 48 Then
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Else: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
ActiveCell.Value = ChrW(&H2716)
ActiveCell.Font.ColorIndex = 2
End If
End If
End Sub



Union() should have two arguments. I don't think you need to use it. Try If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("K15:K31")) Is Nothing Then

The Union method requires two arguments. In your code to use this method is unneccessary. Simply delete it and use only the Range object.
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K15:K31")) Is Nothing Then

Worksheet Events

Black cat's answer resolves your immediate issue.

Here are just some improvements (tips).

You could use .Color (the out-commented values) instead of .ColorIndex to always have the same colors regardless of the color scheme. You'll have to use .ColorIndex = 0 for no formatting though.
You have changed the font color in the Else statements but you're not changing it 'back' in the other cases. Not sure if that's an issue.
In both cases, the Select Case statement looks more readable than the If statement.
In both cases, Cancel = True means that you won't be able to edit the cell so use it only for cells of the given range.
Regarding the 2nd code (Set Cancel = True), the Set keyword is used only for objects (Workbook, Worksheet, Range...) so you cannot use it with a Boolean.




Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Intersect(Me.Range("K15:K31"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Cancel = True
    
    With Target
        Select Case .Interior.ColorIndex
            Case 43
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                .Value = Empty
            Case Else
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 43 ' 52377
                .Font.ColorIndex = 2 ' 16777215
                .Value = ChrW(&H2713)
        End Select
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Intersect(Me.Range("K15:K31"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Cancel = True

    With Target
        Select Case .Interior.ColorIndex
            Case 3
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 48 ' 9868950
                .Value = "N/A"
            Case 48
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            Case Else
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 3 ' 255
                .Font.ColorIndex = 2 ' 16777215
                .Value = ChrW(&H2716)
        End Select
    End With

End Sub

